# How do I check how Gitlab CI rules are being evaluated?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to ensure that my Gitlab CI only runs on a particular host, regardless of the Enable/Disable CI status in the GUI. I have this at the top of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, but CI now runs nowhere. I've confirmed that the host value is as expected by disabling my header and printing it from one of the script jobs.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_SERVER_HOST != "run-here.example.com"'
      when: never
```

In other words, I'm sure that the value of `CI_SERVER_HOST` is `run-here.example.com`, and my pipelines still don't run anywhere. Removing the above header causes them to run everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to add an always to run it in other cases.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
   - if: '$CI_SERVER_HOST != "run-here.example.com"'
     when: never
   - when: always
```

Could you check with this workflow.

Comment: Worked - thanks!

Comment: well that's unfortunatel. would've loved gitlab to properly log or visually show that for us